# alinear horizontalmenrte dos textos en linea

Tags: html, css

necesito que me ayuden a alinear horizontalmente este codigo,
estuve intentado poco porque no tengo mucho tiempo, si alguien me da una
ayudita para poder terminar rapido le agradesco

```css
    .add{
     width:100%;
     display:flex;
          color:white;
    }
    .advertisements{
     margin:auto;
     text-align:center;
    }
    .ad1{
     right:100px;
     float:left;
       padding: 1em 1.5em;
       background:#04091e;
    }
    .ad2{
     float:right;
       padding: 1em 1.5em;
       background:#04091e;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="add">
    <div class="advertisements">
     <div class="d1"><p class="ad1">advertisement</p></div>
     <div class="d2"><p class="ad2">advertisement</p></div>    
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Buenos dias, como que alinearlos horizontalmente? no te entiendo puedes darme mas detalles, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

cambia el display:flex por inline-block

```css
.add{
          dysplay:inline-block;
```